# Book where girl doesn't realise she's magic and raised by ghost parents

Tags: story-identification, novel

The world is split into two realms, that of mortals and fairies (I think), where the fairies are evil and blocked of. Every 50 or 500 years the king can break through for 3 days as a horse to entice a young woman and create an heir, but this time the woman runs away with the child for 17 (?) years and has a family. Unfortunately, she dies but continues to raise the children as a ghost with her husband and sister, until the evil fairies come after the daughter/heir. The girl has to leave her family and head into the mountains with another not so evil fairy to train in order to stop the evil fairy king and her and the not so evil fairy begin to fall in love.

Comment: Please add some proper sentences and paragraph breaks.